# Split string using multiple strings with the separators in the final array

Tags: c#, string, split

I have been searching and found that I can split a string for example "**x += 10**" using multiple strings so I get the result **{ "x", "10" }** but I want to have the separators in the final array too, so it will be **{ "x", " +", "= ", "10" }** using the separators " **+**" and "**=** ". The code I used is `var words = code.Split(Actions.available, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: What if you just split on space instead?

Comment: my real reason of this is too split pieces of code and if the user dont type spaces, it will not be splited nothing so i ended up to split by keywords like "="

Comment: Sounds like you should be parsing the string rather than splitting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regular expressions to parse out the text. By using these rules on creating a *match* of text.

- Any consecutive number
- Any consecutive text
- An individual separator such as `+` or `-` or `=`. *Which is a set in regex speak*
- Ignore any spaces.

The result of from `Regex.Matches` is the output tokenized:

[image]

**Code**

```
var input = "x += 10";
var pattern = @"(\w+|[-=+])";

Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Select(mt => mt.Value);
```

---

**Alternate With Regex Split**

If one uses `Regex.Split` with the same pattern, it splits on everything as we specified as before, but also puts *adds* in the spaces due to its design.

[image]

But to compensate with the addition of a linq extension call on the resulting list, we can remove the spaces and achieve the same answer.

```
Regex.Split(input, @"(\w+|[-=+])")
     .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
```

result is `{ "x", "+", "=", "10" }`

Comment: You don't need two capture groups, just use the or inside of one `(\w+|[+-=])`

Comment: I have updated the code, which thanks juharr, simplifies the linq code as well as the pattern. Who would 'ove thought, "less is better". :-)

Comment: Typically when dealing with a non-generic collection and Linq (and you know it only contains one type) you just use `Cast<Match>()`

Comment: Updated answer to incorporate the usage of `Regex.Split`.